# adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,list_msg.size()); not working

Tags: java, android

How do I add new data that comes in from a user at the bottom of recyclerview?

```
m = editTextMsg.getText().toString();
sm.setMessage(m);
editTextMsg.setText("");
Postchat_text();
sm.setProfile(img_url);
sm.setTime(String.valueOf(date));
list_msg.add(0,sm);
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,list_msg.size()); // not working when add data at bo
msg_list.scrollToPosition(1);
```

Comment: post your data adding code and adapter code here

Comment: Define 'not working'.

Answer (score 0):

Call :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Instead of :

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,list_msg.size());
```